# Why I see white screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using SceneKit and I'm new in it. Just made a simple playground project that shows .scn object

Here is my code:

```
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

public class SceneViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

    var sceneView: SCNView!
    var scene: SCNScene!

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        view.addSubview(sceneView)

        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "MilkyWay.scn")!
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.isPlaying = true
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is "MilkyWay.scn" a valid file in your Playground project?

Comment: Yes. It is valid file in my project

Comment: I just called SceneView in viewWillAppear method and it still the same

Answer (score 0):

When `viewDidLoad` runs, your VC's view has no frame setup yet.

You need to set `sceneView`'s frame after the layout system is done - this means you should do this either in `viewDidAppear`, or, better, whenever the frame changes in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

The following are a few questions to help debug and for us to get a better idea of what might be wrong.

Does the scn file have a camera inside of it?
Is that camera inside or outside of the mesh?
Is the material on the mesh double sided, or have inverted normals?

Does the following code show the scene correctly? (knocking it back to its simplest components)

```
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport


let sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:800, height:800))
let scene = SCNScene(named: "MilkyWay.scn")!


sceneView.showsStatistics = true
sceneView.scene = scene
sceneView.isPlaying = true

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(sceneView)
```

Answer (score 0):

The view layout always for subviews takes place after viewdid load. So, the frame defined by you in viewDidLoad did not take place. So, define this in viewDidAppear method. 
I have faced this problem for WKWebview. When I provided a frame to WKWebView in viewDidAppear method, I got the visuals of my WKWebView. Otherwise, if we define frames in viewDidLoad they did not get the frames.

Like this:-

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
      view.addSubview(sceneView)
}
```